# N1ql query for Array_Append control for exiting elelment

Tags: json, couchbase, sql++

This is my updated document when i execute query for first time the outcome is Result1  and again i execute query once again outcome is Result2.

Query:

UPDATE default AS d SET e.contact = ARRAY_APPEND(e.contact,{ "email": "sri123@gmail.com", "phone": 9876655555 })
                               FOR e IN d.details WHEN e.id = 1234 END
    WHERE META().id = "k01";

Result1:

```
 "k01":
    {
      "details": [
        {
          "id": 1234,
          "city": "Medway",
          "country": "United Kingdom",
          "name": "Medway Youth Hostel",
          "url": "http://www.yha.org.uk",
          "contact": [
            {
              "email": "hari34@gmail.com",
              "phone": 6789435634
            }
              ]
        }]
    }
```

Result 2:

```
 "k01":
    {
      "details": [
        {
          "id": 1234,
          "city": "Medway",
          "country": "United Kingdom",
          "name": "Medway Youth Hostel",
          "url": "http://www.yha.org.uk",
          "contact": [
            {
              "email": "hari34@gmail.com",
              "phone": 6789435634
            },
            {
              "email": "hari34@gmail.com",
              "phone": 6789435634
            }
              ]
        }]
    }
```

How can i control the duplicate values, When i execute the query for second time with same values.Everytime fields are inserting with same values irrespective of elements exists or not. please suggest me(Query). So that no duplicate appends will happen

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE default AS d SET e.contact = ARRAY_APPEND(e.contact,{ "email": "sri123@gmail.com", "phone": 9876655555 }) FOR e IN d.details WHEN e.id = 1234 END WHERE META().id = "k01" AND ANY  e IN d.details SATISFIES e.id = 1234 AND { "email": "sri123@gmail.com", "phone": 9876655555 } NOT IN e.contact END;

This one is better if the contact present no update will happen.

OR

UPDATE default AS d SET e.contact = ARRAY_DISTINCT(ARRAY_APPEND(e.contact,{ "email": "sri123@gmail.com", "phone": 9876655555 })) FOR e IN d.details WHEN e.id = 1234 END WHERE META().id = "k01";

UPDATE default AS d SET e.contact = ARRAY_APPEND(e.contact,{ "email": "sri123@gmail.com", "phone": 9876655555 }) FOR e IN d.details WHEN e.id = 1234 AND { "email": "sri123@gmail.com", "phone": 9876655555 } NOT IN e.contact  END WHERE META().id = "k01";

This causes Update even contact present.

Comment: If i take out the phone number it appends the duplicate values again in document  when i execute the query 1 and query 3 : UPDATE default AS d SET e.contact = ARRAY_APPEND(e.contact,{ "email": "sri123@gmail.com", "phone": 9876655555 }) FOR e IN d.details WHEN e.id = 1234 END WHERE META().id = "k01" AND ANY e IN d.details SATISFIES e.id = 1234 AND { "email": "sri123@gmail.com"} NOT IN e.contact END;

Comment: Is duplicate check is on whole document or field. If you need to check on email change condition. SATISFIES e.id = 1234 AND AND "sri123@gmail.com" NOT IN e.contact[*].email END